# http-server doesnt serve up any files

Tags: node.js, localhost

So im trying to make my localhost server up https to do some testing with webhooks, i was looking into `http-server` and i can get the https server up and running, but it wont server any content for my MERN application, it simply just downloads the file from the browser. I need to be able to server up my application from the localhost over https, but it seems that `http-server` only creates a web server... im sure if i was serving static content this might work, but it doesnt.

does anyone have any idea how to proceed? the goal is to ensure i can setup an `https://localhost:3000` that i will expose on my router so i can take in content from a different API via a webhook and see what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setting up a https server can be done easily.

```js
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync( 'privatekey.pem' );
var certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'certificate.pem' );

https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, app).listen(port);
```

See the Node docs for more info: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Then you need to use a router to serve the application logic.

Comment: except this isnt static content, its a MERN stack application i need a way to get it to start my node server, at `server/server.js` if i can get it to start that and respond, then this would work

Comment: Sorry Austin, I did not read your question correctly. Let me rewrite my answer.

Comment: thanks for that, this is exactly what i needed, i had to modify it slightly, but the Node Docs you pointed to were quite helpful with that, thanks for looking out!